# Why my shaders half broken on some android devices?

Tags: unity3d-shaders

I have shaders that cut hole in other meshes. On some android devices game starts bugy. After some time it fixes itself. When i reload scene it occurs again.

Here is broken one

[image]

Here is right one

[image]